# Pandas read_csv get numbers wrong when infering the dype

Tags: python, pandas, types, type-inference

read_csv in pandas reads a column of numbers with missing values as Float64 by default and gets the numbers wrong. I'd like to understand why read_csv chooses a data type that is not suitable and if there is a way around that other than manually specifying the data types I want.

The csv file I'm trying to import looks like this:

```
var1,var2
20190121080540088085780399,
20190121081907086084200299,-3510076284811963185
20190121082131086094750399,
20190121082828088034200299,
20190121083251091014220199,-8914359668388912530
```

and var2 is the columns that read_csv doesn't read correctly

I import the file with read_csv without specifying dtype= myself:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("/Outputs/test.csv").fillna(0) # read the file
df["var3"]=df["var2"].astype("int64")  # var3 displays the var2 as Int
df
```

it returns wrong values for var2:

```
                         var1          var2                 var3
0  20190121080540088085780399  0.000000e+00                    0
1  20190121081907086084200299 -3.510076e+18 -3510076284811963392
2  20190121082131086094750399  0.000000e+00                    0
3  20190121082828088034200299  0.000000e+00                    0
4  20190121083251091014220199 -8.914360e+18 -8914359668388912128
```

var2 doesn't have the correct values (e.g -3510076284811963392 instead of -3510076284811963185). I suspect it's because float64 is not enough for these large numbers.

```
df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 5 entries, 0 to 4
Data columns (total 3 columns):
var1    5 non-null object
var2    5 non-null float64
var3    5 non-null int64
dtypes: float64(1), int64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 192.0+ bytes
```

==> Why doesn't read_csv choose a suitable data type for var? For instance var1, the dtype is object which is fine.
Is there any way to force to_csv to read large numbers as object instead of float64? 
I can specify the dtype myself... but I'd like to avoid that if I can as I'd like to write a function I can re-use even if the names of the columns change.

Comment: You can make a dict of dtypes to pass in when you read the csv.

Comment: Wow, you'd think this is what `float_precision='round_trip'` would raise on. You're right, that's what it is...